# Consolidation of Free Space on Ext4

Tags: linux, partitioning, defragment

I'm building an linux installation which then will be pushed to various devices with different means of mass storage. Therefore, I'd like to shorten the partitions lengths before creating an image to dd it to various differently-sized media. For this, I'd like to consolidate all files to the beginning of ext4 partitions and moving all free space to the end.

Unfortunatelly I did not find any way to do this. Is there a tool to do this?

Comment: No specific tools, but you can create another image of desired size, then rsync everything on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resize2fs` to explicitly shrink your ext4 filesystem to a given size. You first unmount the volume, run `fsck` to make sure the volume has no errors that could confuse the resizing program (not strictly needed, but better safe than sorry), and then run a:

```shell
resize2fs /dev/[volume where the filesystem resides] 500M
```

If the target size is smaller than the amount of data you have on the volume, the program will complain and tell you the minimum size (in blocks).

When you are done with the dump and want to add files to your partition, running `resize2fs` without a size resizes it to the partition size.